# How do I remove particular $x$ and $y$ values from a list of data points?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have data points of the form `{x,y,z}`:

```
s = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}
```

And I need to remove *entire data points* based on a condition. For example, let's say that I want to remove any data points where `z > 6`. The result should be this:

```
s2 = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

How do I do this? I think `DeleteCases` might be the way to go, but I'm still fairly inexperienced with Mathematica and am not sure how to use this function to make this work.

Comment: Have you seen [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
s2 = Pick[s, Thread[s[[All, 3]] > 6], False]
```

or

```
s2 = Pick[s, Thread[s[[All, 3]] <= 6]]
```

> {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}

Comment: Can this be used to set upper *and lower bounds* for a coordinate in one go?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat You can write `Thread[4 <= s[[All, 3]] <= 6]`

Comment: @what, you might also be interested in the function `Between[]`.

Answer (score 4):

`DeleteCases` works perfectly here, although I think `Select` is a bit more natural

```
DeleteCases[s, {_, _, _?(# > 6 &)}]
Select[s, Last@# <= 6 &]

(* {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}} *)
(* {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}} *)
```